# using jQuery to edit an sql record

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to load into a form an existing data from a database, and allow the user to edit and update it. but for some reason, when the edited data is sent by ajax, all the fields are empty. The loading of the current data, setting it into the fields and the sql query itself, seems to work fine.
so i am really lost here.

```
 //bootstrap modal 
<!--- Edit Campaign Modal------->

                <div id="editCampaignModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Cmapaign Details:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div id="new-campaign-com-with-server">
                                    <div id="edit-campaign-add-msg"></div>
                                    <form  role="form" id="edit-campaign-form" class="campaign-form" method="post" action="newCampaign.php">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="ecname">Name:         </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ecname" name="cname">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="eproduct">Product:     </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eproduct" name="product">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>                                      
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="euserId">User ID:     </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="euserId" name="userId">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>            
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="esource">Source:       </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="esource" name="source">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>                                                                             <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="eformat">Format:       </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eformat" name="format">
                                                                                                                                     </div>
                                                                                                                                </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="etype">Type:           </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="etype" name="type">
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>                                                                              <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="ecostType">Cost Type:   </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ecostType" name="costType">
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>                                                                                   <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="ecostValue">Cost Value: </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ecostValue" name="CostValue">
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="esaleType">Sale Type:   </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="esaleType" name="saleType">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="esaleValue">Sale Value: </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="esaleValue" name="saleValue">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="einsertPixel">Insert Pixel:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="einsertPixel" name="insertPixel">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="etimeZone">Time Zone:   </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="etimeZone" name="timeZone">
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <h2>Alerts</h2>
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="eUVLLow">UVL Low:    </label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eUVLLow" name="UVLLow">
                                                </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="eUVLHigh">UVL High:   </label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eUVLHigh" name="UVLHigh">
                                            </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="eCPLLow">CPL Low:    </label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eCPLLow" name="CPLLow">
                                            </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="eCPLHigh">CPL High:    </label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eCPLHigh" name="CPLHigh">
                                            </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit-form">Update Changes</button>
                                    </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!------------------------------>
```

//The jQuery script

```
         function editCampaign(queryArr)
        {
            //loading all the array data in to the form
            $("#ecname").val(queryArr[1]);
//            document.getElementById('ecname').value=queryArr[1];
            $("#eproduct").val(queryArr[2]);
            $("#euserId").val(queryArr[3]);
            $("#esource").val(queryArr[4]);
            $("#eformat").val(queryArr[5]);
            $("#etype").val(queryArr[6]);
            $("#ecostType").val(queryArr[7]);
            $("#ecostValue").val(queryArr[8]);
            $("#esaleType").val(queryArr[9]);
            $("#esaleValue").val(queryArr[10]);
            $("#einsertPixel").val(queryArr[11]);
            $("#etimeZone").val(queryArr[12]);
            $("#eUVLLow").val(queryArr[13]);
            $("#eUVLHigh").val(queryArr[14]);
            $("#eCPLLow").val(queryArr[15]);
            $("#eCPLHigh").val(queryArr[16]);
            $("#edit-campaign-add-msg").hide();
            $("#edit-campaign-form").show();
            $('#editCampaignModal').modal({show: true});

        }

      function getRowId(event)
        {
            id = $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('td').eq(0).html();
        }



 $(document).ready(function() {
        //event fired on edit campaign 'update changes' button press
        $("#edit-campaign-form").submit(function(event){
            var data = {
                            "CID": id
                        };
            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "updateCampaignEditChanges.php", 
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                            $("#edit-campaign-add-msg").show();
                            $("#edit-campaign-add-msg").html("Success, Form Updated!");
                            $("#edit-campaign-form").hide();
                        }
                    });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

//the php code for Updating the changes
//without form validation for now

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
  test_function();
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&        strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function()
{

    $servername = "************.com";
    $username = "*************";
    $password = "**********";
    $dbname = "******";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    else
    {
        $ID=$_POST["CID"];
        $CNAME= $_POST["ecname"];
        $PRODUCT= $_POST["eproduct"];
        $USERID= $_POST["euserId"];
        $SOURCE= $_POST["esource"]; 
        $FORMAT= $_POST["eformat"];
        $TYPE= $_POST["etype"]; 
        $COSTTYPE= $_POST["ecostType"];
        $COSTVALUE= $_POST["ecostValue"];
        $SALETYPE= $_POST["esaleType"];
        $SALEVALUE= $_POST["esaleValue"];
        $INSERTPIXEL= $_POST["einsertPixel"];
        $TIMEZONE= $_POST["etimeZone"];
        $UVLLOW= $_POST["eUVLLow"];
        $UVLHIGH= $_POST["eUVLHight"];
        $CPLLOW= $_POST["eCPLLow"];
        $CPLHIGH= $_POST["eCPLHigh"];
        $sql = "UPDATE campaign
SET name='$CNAME',
product='$PRODUCT',
user_id='$USERID',
source='$SOURCE',
format='$FORMAT',
type='$TYPE',
cost_type='$COSTTYPE',
cost_value='$COSTVALUE',
sale_type='$SALETYPE',
sale_value='$SALEVALUE',
insert_pixel='$INSERTPIXEL',
time_zone='$TIMEZONE',
uvl_low='$UVLLOW',
uvl_high='$UVLHIGH',
cpl_low='$CPLLOW',
cpl_high='$CPLHIGH'
WHERE cid='$ID'";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
        $conn->close();

            if(isset($_POST["ecname"]))
            $result="field was passed correctly :)";
        else
            $result="field is empty! :O";


     echo json_encode($result);

}



?>
```

i am really sorry for the exceptionally long form, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP to process the form submission is looking for the wrong variables. You are looking for the form field `ID`s when you should be looking for the form field `name`s. When you submit a form, the `name` attribute is used as the key, not the `id`. Either change your HTML to make the `name` attribute match the `id` or change your PHP to use the `name` attribute as the key.

Comment: Thank you so much, i completely forgot about it when i copied the original form for creating a record.
you made my day :)